# Apache2 RewriteRule not working in a container of image docker.io/library/php:7.4-apache

Tags: php, apache, docker, mod-rewrite, containers

**Main problem:**

`http://localhost/mysite/source/aphpfile.php` works.

`http://localhost/mysite/aphpfile` does not work despite a rewrite rule to run `aphpfile.php`.

I tried with the server placed in containers run from `php:7.2-apache` and `php:7.4-apache` container images from `docker.io/library/`. I had the same problem in both. When I try locally, the RewriteRule works perfectly. I want it to work in a container.

**Folder structure on the disk (inside container):**

`/var/www/html/mysite/source/aphpfile.php`

No `.htaccess` files included.

**Configuration:**

1. Unmodified `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` file.
2. `a2enmod rewrite`
3. `a2ensite mysite.conf`
4. `a2enmod info`

With `http://localhost/server-info` loading correct configuration is confirmed:

```
Current Configuration: (from server-info page)
In file: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf
   1: <Directory "var/www/html/mysite/">
   7:   RewriteEngine On
   9:   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  10:   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  11:   RewriteRule ^aphpfile /var/www/html/mysite/source/aphpfile.php [L]
    : </Directory>
```

Also the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf`:

```
<Directory  "var/www/html/mysite/">
   Options +Indexes
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^aphpfile /var/www/html/mysite/source/aphpfile.php [L] # <---- this line works in non-container server despite starting with /var/...
        #to be sure, I tried also with ^/aphpfile ^mysite/aphpfile
        # ^/mysite/aphpfile in additional lines seperately to point
        # to /var/www/html/mysite/source/aphpfile.php [L]
        # edit1, include exact lines I tried
        # RewriteRule ^aphpfile /var/www/html/mysite/source/aphpfile.php [L] # <---- this line works in non-container server despite starting with /var/...
        # RewriteRule ^aphpfile source/aphpfile.php [L] # <---- this I tried today after comment from @Daniel Farrell but no change in the result
        # RewriteRule ^/aphpfile /var/www/html/mysite/source/aphpfile.php [L]
        # RewriteRule ^source/aphpfile /var/www/html/mysite/source/aphpfile.php [L]
        # RewriteRule ^/aphpfile /var/www/html/mysite/source/aphpfile.php [L]
</Directory>
```

**Logs:**

1. `/var/log/apache2/access.log`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2020:14:01:36 +0000] "GET /mysite/aphpfile HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36"
```

2. `/var/log/apache2/error.log`: shows no error related this particular
   request.

**Extra details:**

1. Using `podman` (not docker)
2. `podman exec -it <containername> bash` to access/modify a container.
3. Took care of restarting `apache2` service, verifying site and mod are enabled.

`edit2`

**Not a solution to the problem but I'm moving on with alternative:**

This way all functionality along with rewrite rule works.

Created new image:

```
#Dockerfile
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN apt update -y \
 && apt install -y apache2 php php-<many extensions> \
 && apt clean all
#COPY <source> <dest>
#RUN <a2enmod, a2ensite>
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

Still don't know why the official `php:7.x-apache` images are not working. (Bug?)

Comment: "#to be sure, I tried also with ^/aphpfile ^mysite/aphpfile ^/mysite/aphpfile "   You're onto something there.  `^aphpfile` doesn't match `/mysite/aphpfile`.  I would want to see the examples that didn't work in the server info output before I just assumed you had done that correctly.  When I assume, i miss valid data points that can keep my  analysis accurate.  :P

Comment: Another point, `RewriteRule` rewrites to a URI location, not a path on the underlying filesystem.  So Probably if you did have the regex written properly, you'd be writing the url to literally `https://servername/var/www/html/mysite/source/aphpfile.php` which would then attempt to read from the docroot, something like /var/www/html/var/www/html/mysite/source/aphpfile.php`, which would indeed be a 404.

Comment: @Daniel Farrell, thank you for the comments, edited the original post to include exact lines that I had tried. Please search for edit1 term in the post. Because `mysite.conf` has, `<Directory  "var/www/html/mysite/">`, I am searching for `^aphpfile`, which works correctly in a non-container server. Also, Instead if written `<Directory "var/www/html/">`, then searching `^mysite/aphpfile` works in non-container server and with target being absolute path of the file (starting with /var/...). None of these work when server is a container.